# Why do we have a three dimensional array when accessing each character in each string* in an array of pointers to strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm looking over past homework assignments from last year, and I never got around to figuring out why this works for checking if each string in an array is a palindrome (word spelt backwards is the same word - 'racecar'):

```
for (int k = 0; k < numElems; k++){
    pStatus = true;
    lastLetter = (*ptrArray[k]).length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (lastLetter / 2); i++){
        if (ptrArray[k][0][i] != ptrArray[k][0][lastLetter - i]) 
            pStatus = false;
    }
    if (pStatus == true){
        //...
    }
}
```

If I remember correctly, I wrote this code through trial and error when two dimensions would give me strange results. I was just messing with the code and trying weird things after being frustrated with it not working.

So to access each indvidual character in each string in the array I need to write `ptrArray[k][0][lastLetter - i]` instead of `ptrArray[k][lastLetter - i]`.  Why is this?

---

Edit:

Some of you guys wanted more code, and I think I overlooked the fact that ptrArray is a pointer of pointers to strings (I recall that we had to use a pointer to array of pointers in this assignment). Is this why we need to introduce `[0]`? Here's the function's prototype:

```
void checkIfPalindrome(string **ptrArray, int numElems);
```

And I dynamically allocated the array of pointers.

```
string **ptrArray;
ptrArray = new string*[numElems];
```

Comment: What's the type of `ptrArray`?

Comment: My guess would be that it is something like container or array of pointers to strings, (e.g. `std::vector<std::string*>`)

Comment: Hi. From the variable naming convention it seems ptrArray is an array of pointers, of the datatype string. Can you please share the complete code, especially the part where you define the variables. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, I completely overlooked that it's a dynamically allocated array of pointers to strings. I made some edits above if you want to look them over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type is `string**`.  `string` is itself an array-type, so we effectively have a three-dimensional array.  `ptrArray[k]` accesses a pointer to a `string`, `ptrArray[k][0]` accesses a `string` (effectively equivalent to `*(ptrArray[k])`), and `ptrArray[k][0][i]` accesses the `i`th character in the "first" string of the array pointed to by the pointer in address `ptrArray[k]`.

Comment: I guess now I'm just not understanding for what reason we have an added dimension to access the actual string character. It doesn't make sense to me that a pointer is an array (because here it's acting like one, right?) which requires the second dimension `[0]` - But using just two dimensions gave me weird results. Was I just accessing "random" memory addresses? 

If I had a pointer named `ptr`, will `ptr[j]` allow you to 'jump' in memory from the address stored by ptr?

Comment: @Biiiiiird: You actually have it backwards. It is not pointers that act as arrays. It is arrays that act as pointers.  When you say `A[N]`, that is fundamentally a pointer operation, not an array operation. In fact, the expression `A[N]` is equivalent to (in fact, defined as) `*(A + N)`. In the case that `A` is not a pointer, but an array, it is implicitly converted to a pointer for this operation. And in the case that `N` is 0, the expression is equivalent to `*A`, a simple pointer dereference.

Comment: Ah I can't believe I forgot that about `A[N]` being a pointer operation, and now that makes so much more sense! Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions about your code since all the variables used aren't in scope. Let's try writing the algorithm in pseudo-code.

```
strings = [ "str1", "str2",... ]

for each s in strings:
    is_palindrome = true

    last_index = s.length - 1

    for i in [0, last_index]:
        if s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(last_index - i)
            is_palindrome = false

    if is_palindrome == true:
       #...
```

You're only actually using two dimensions in your algorithm since you always access the 0th element in the second dimension. So we could rewrite your code like

```
std::vector<std::string> ptrArray = ...;
int numElems = ptrArray.length();

for (int k = 0; k < numElems; k++){
    pStatus = true;

    lastLetter = ptrArray[k].length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (lastLetter / 2); i++){

        if (ptrArray[k][i] != ptrArray[k][lastLetter - i]) {

            pStatus = false;

        }

    }

    if (pStatus == true){
        //...
    }
}
```

Where `ptrArray` is the array of the strings `ptrArray[i]` is the i-th string and `ptrArray[i][j]` is the j-th character of the i-th string.